# NFS Underground 2 screen problem on Linux

Tags: 14.04, wine, nfs

so i  have the windows version of nfs underground 2 on my linux pc. When i start it up with wine or open the .exe file directly only one quarter of the game window shows on the screen. It doesnt fit on the whole screen. the game seems to be working fine apart from the screen problem. Does anyone know how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have "emulate virtual desktop" option set with resolution lower than in-game resolution. Try to disable this setting or increase resolution of virtual desktop

Answer (score 0):

Start `winecfg` go to Graphics and select `Emulate virtual desktop`.
Make sure to select the right resolution.